# Group multiple emissions from different observables into one emission

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have the following 3 observables:

```
Observable<List<Action>> actions

Observable<List<Type>> types

Observable<List<Unit>> units
```

I want to observe all emissions from all observables and put them in a Hash Map:

From first observable

```
hashMap.put("Actions", actions);
```

From second observable

```
hashMap.put("Types", types);
```

From third observable

```
hashMap.put("Units", units);
```

Then I want to emit the `hashMap` once all observables are completed.

Note:

- The hash map can be `HashMap<String, List<Object>>`
- It is OK to use `instanceof`
- I want to use current operators (no custom ones)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Zip — combine the emissions of multiple Observables together via a
>   specified function and emit single items for each combination based on
>   the results of this function

You are looking for the [zip](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html) operator. Zip actions, types and units Observables and create your Hash Map in the combine function. The result will be an Observable of Hash Map.